# Multiple background colors for css nested divs

Tags: css, html, background-color

Alright.  This is the situation.  I have created a website with a black banner at the top with a logo, its height is 100px and its background color is #000.  Next I want a large "main_content" div to encompass the navigation along with any content within the page, so it would not include the footer.  In this case there are several nested divs within the main_content area of the page and there is already a background color defined for them.  The issue is that once I apply a background color to the div called "main_content" it only applies it to the navigation bar and then stops because it runs into the nested div that already has a color defined.  I'm wondering if there is  CSS rule I am missing here...

The only fix I have found is that I MUST define a height for the main_content div, is there a way around this? I don't want to have to define a height for the content area because I want it to just match the height of the content that fills it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is most likely happening is that your other nested divs are inheriting the color from their parent main_content div, to fix this you should provide the color explicitly for your nested divs. Other thing you mentioned is that you want to apply height to main_content as per its content you can do so by giving it a height of 100% eg:

```
<style>
#main_content{height:100%;}
</style>
```

Comment: `height:100%;` would make it fill up all of its parent's height vertically, not all of its content's height vertically.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it, overflow:hidden, im not sure if this is the right solution but its the best I've got